# How to save a world in Minecraft Pocket Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My friend has Minecraft Pocket Edition on his Android tablet. He was asking me how to save it because he can't find the save button. How do you save the world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressing 'Quit to Title' in the menu will automatically save your world for you.

You must have the full version in order to save your worlds. ($6.99)

Comment: I need to pay 6.99 dollars for it?! I'm in the Philippines and don't have money to buy full version. But still solves my problem

Answer (score -2):

Press the quit to title button will save the game for you,